# Why bitwise AND gives different byte?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

A byte in java is 8 bit long. A `&` operator does a bitwise `and`operation.

A hexadecimal representation takes two hex-chars `0-F`.

A `0xFF` is one byte.

If I think about the `&` operation I think the processor does this:

```
   Bit no: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
   Binary: 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 = decimal 2
Operation: & & & & & & & &
    Value: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 = 0xFF
----------------------------------------
   Result: 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 = decimal 2
```

Because all binaries remain unchanged, it leads me to think that we do not need the `& 0xFF`.

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte b = -1;
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(b).concat(" and ").concat(String.valueOf(b & 0xFF)));
}
```

**Result**

```
-1 and 255
```

If my assumption (we don't need `& 0xFF`) is correct, why the difference?

Comment: Try `byte c = b & 0xFF;`. You might be surprised.

Comment: @PeterRader To be more specific about the issue, `0xFF` is an `int`, not a `byte`, so `b & 0xFF` is also an `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0xFF` is equal to an int with the value of `255`, or `00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111`. A byte -1 is `11111111`, and because it is signed, this is interpreted as `-1`. If it was unsigned, this would also be `255`.

When you `&` the two values, Java will return the result in the type of the larger of the two values, which is `int`, so the final result is an int with bits `00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111`, which evaluates to `255`.

Comment: Both answers are correct, but you need the reputation.

Answer (score 2):

`0xFF` is an `int`, not a `byte`, so `b & 0xFF` is also an `int`. To get the result you want, you either need to do `byte` arithmetic (which Java doesn't allow -- all datatypes smaller than `int` are implicitly converted to `int` before performing operations), or your mask `0xFF` must have `1`'s for *every* bit in the `int` (all 32 of them). See for example the following:

```
System.out.println(0xFF);            // 255. (only 8 of 32 bits are 1)
System.out.println((int)0xFF);       // 255. (only 8 of 32 bits are 1)
System.out.println((byte)0xFF);      // -1. (all 8 of 8 bits are 1)
System.out.println((int)(byte)0xFF); // -1. (all 32 of 32 bits are 1)
```

Note that by casting to `byte` and back to `int`, we cause all 32 bits to be `1`. Hence, the following code does what you want (note there's an implicit cast to `int` after the explicit cast to `byte`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte b = -1;
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(b) + " and " + String.valueOf(b & (byte)0xFF)));
}
```

Output:

> -1 and -1

Comment: Note, however, that the result of `b & (byte)0xFF` is still `int`. Java never does arithmetic with anything smaller than `int`, so `b & (byte)0xFF` is implicitly equivalent to `(int)b & (int)(byte)0xFF`. https://ideone.com/Qr64iB